# Secure Gateway to DB2 zOS - Bluemix - SQL1598N

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, db2-connect, db2-zos

I have an issue with an error SQL1598N, between Bluemix and a Secure Gateway to access DB2 z/Os with PHP. The gateway client is Windows and is running on my system.
I have a license type "Client Device" for a product "db2conpe".

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: Hi,
with db2_pconnect (PHP from Bluemix), the error code is SQL1598N. The Hostname and Port is the address of Gateway with a client who run under Windows 7. On the Gateway log I see my request, open and close.

Comment: Consider editing your question, so people’s see your problem on the first glance.

Comment: Secure Gateway is unaware of the connection types running through it. I'm not sure on how the licenses play in (or where they should be located apart from the DB host) but I'd suggest looking here and seeing if this helps at all: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21635635